# sampling values in array with good performance

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a function which takes an array of values and a sampling rate. The function should remove values randomly by the sampling rate. For instance a sampling rate of 20% should remove 20% of the values. How can I achieve this with a very good performance, because I will iterate over more than 10.000 values?

My idea is something like

```
for(var i = values.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    if(rnd < samplingRate)
        values.splice(i,1);
}
```

but I think the `Math.random()` function is no performant choice.

Comment: First I need a clarification: Do you want to remove 20% of all values as you describe in the text, or remove each value with a chance of 20%, which is what you are doing in the code? They are two very different things. In any case there is no way around `Math.random`, unless you write your own RNG, which hardly will perform better.

Comment: I did an edit for my question. It is like I have written in the text.

Comment: I don't think many `splice` operations after each other have a good performance (the `Math.random` call should be negligible in comparison). You might want to try [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead (although that creates a new array, instead of removing them from `values`)

Comment: Have you edited yet? I don't see anything. Are you saying your code has nothing to do with the problem? Can you post your attempt at code that solves the problem, and not something else.

Comment: I think my code should solve the problem of my text. But it doesn't matter, I just wanted to have a better approach for this.

Comment: No it doesn't. You text says you want to remove 20% of the values. If you have 10.000 values, then that means you'll end up with exactly 8.000 values. With your code you'll have any number of values between 0 and 10.000.

Comment: Now I understand. You are right. I want to remove exactly 20% of the values randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no need to iterate over the whole array if you only want to operate on 20% of it.
Loop for *n* times where `n = Math.floor(0.20 * originalArray.length) - 1` and on each iteration [get a random element from the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-random-value-from-an-array) and remove it.

Comment: Nice approach! I will use and mark this as answer when there is no better way to do this.

Comment: That would the first 20% of the values not random 20%.

Comment: @RoToRa: No, he means "remove a random element (out of the whole array) for n (= 0.2 * values.length) times"

Comment: @Bergi Imagine what would happen if the percentage was 100.

Comment: @Nit: So what? Loop `n` times (e.g. from `0` to `n-1` as usual). Where `n` could be anything from `0` to `values.length`.

Comment: That's exactly what the `-1` is there for, to loop to `n-1` in case of 100%.

Comment: If the length of the array is 5, n will equal zero where it should equal one.  That's why you don't subtract one.  When you finally construct your loop that is where you should use n - 1.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to support older browsers use the [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
var samplingPercentage = samplingRate / 100;

var filtered = values.filter(function() {
  return Math.random() < samplingPercentage;
});
```

Comment: This will remove elements with 20% probability, not remove 20% of the elements.

Comment: I know. But that seems what the OP wants according to his/her comments. I'm not sure.

Comment: Reading the comments now, likewise not certain, it's ambiguous.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant that I want to remove 20 % of the elements randomly.